# python 2.7.6 printing strings vertically while using loops

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a code that needs to print a string vertically. How do i do this? Someone in my class told me to try this:

```
string = raw_input ('Please enter a string. ')
    while string() true:
        print string().
```

I tried this and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print each character of a string on a new line, you can iterate over the string:

```
user_input = raw_input ('Please enter a string. ')  # store the string if a variable 
for c in user_input:        # for each character 'c' in the input
     print(c)               # print it. The print function add a new line character at each call
```